# show data only of least date if not available then whatever date is available in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns project Id, project name, period and status.

I only want a unique row with project Id with least/minmum period.

```
Project ID  |   Project name |  Period  | Status
-----------------------------------------------
1234877     |   abc      |01-01-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
34277822    |   bcd      |01-01-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
34277822    |   bcd      |01-02-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
34277822    |   bcd      |01-03-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
34277822    |   bcd      |01-04-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
66277261    |   efg      |01-01-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
4526373     |   hij      |01-07-2020| Closed
--------------------------------------------------
234532      |   jkl      |01-02-2020| Closed
--------------------------------------------------
234532      |   jkl      |01-03-2020| Closed
--------------------------------------------------
526263      |   mno      |01-01-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
8282827     |   pqr      |01-01-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
212333      |   stu      |01-07-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
8977552     |   vwx      |01-01-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
8977552     |   vwx      |01-02-2020| Closed
-----------------------------------------------------
8977552     |   vwx      |01-03-2020| Closed
------------------------------------------------------
8977552     |   vwx      |01-04-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------------
8977552     |   vwx      |01-05-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Output I want is

```
Project ID  |   Project name |  Period  | Status
-----------------------------------------------
1234877     |   abc      |01-01-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
34277822    |   bcd      |01-01-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
66277261    |   efg      |01-01-2020| Closed
-------------------------------------------------
4526373     |   hij      |01-07-2020| Closed
--------------------------------------------------
234532      |   jkl      |01-02-2020| Closed
--------------------------------------------------
526263      |   mno      |01-01-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
8282827     |   pqr      |01-01-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
212333      |   stu      |01-07-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
8977552     |   vwx      |01-01-2020| Closed
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.period = (select min(t2.period)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.project_id = t.project_id
                 );
```

With an index on `(project_id, period)` this often has the best best performance in many databases.